# Creating Ubuntu Live CD with customized Unity launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, live-cd, gsettings, uck

I would like to create a custom Ubuntu image based on Natty using Ubuntu Customization Kit. I also want to customize the icons appearing on the Unity Launcher.

I can change the icons on my desktop system with the following command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['firefox.desktop', 'nautilus-home.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop']"
```

I tried to run this command from the UCK console while creating the Live CD, but it doesn’t seem to work.

Do you have any ideas how I could solve this?

Comment: I don't know a fix for this, but I do know why it didn't work: Running gsettings as root doesn't work and that's how UCK or any other tool like this runs all the commands...

Comment: Probably related: [How to make applications pinned in launcher appear for all users?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73096/how-to-make-applications-pinned-in-launcher-appear-for-all-users)

Comment: Toros, have you found a solution? ( [Question 156932](http://askubuntu.com/questions/156932) may be related)

Comment: After check, shhac's answer did the trick for me (except i used 10_local-unity-launcher.gschema.override, but com.canonical.Unity.gschema.override will probably also work).

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised nobody has answered this yet, it is done in a schema so you make an override and re-compile.

```
echo "[com.canonical.Unity.Launcher]
favorites=['firefox.desktop', 'nautilus-home.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop']" > /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.Unity.gschema.override

glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

You can probably edit the xml and re-compile for the same result but I've not managed to get this to work yet (trial and error is tedious when you're trying to make live cd/usbs).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for ubuntu 13.10 ... did they change anything regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried either [APTonCD](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/) or [Remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/)?