# How to make applications pinned in launcher appear for all users?

Tags: launcher

I need to pin an application in Unity launcher such that it can be seen for all users.

Currently, everything I changed seems to only affect the local user.

Answer (score 8):

To make appear applications pinned in launcher for newly created users you can change default settings schema by setting up a new override:

Create file `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_local-unity-launcher.gschema.override` and insert the following code (`.desktop` files are stored under `/usr/share/applications/`):

```
[com.canonical.Unity.Launcher]
favorites=['pinned-application1.desktop', 'pinned-application2.desktop']
```

You have to insert all pinned applications. See `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.Unity.gschema.xml` for default values by searching settings schema and key:

```
        <schema path="/desktop/unity/launcher/" id="com.canonical.Unity.Launcher" gettext-domain="unity">
    <key type="as" name="favorites">
      <default>DEFAULT_VALUES</default>
```

Then recompile schemas file `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/gschemas.compiled` (which is used by gsettings):

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```