# Command to change Gnome 3 setting system-wide (for all users)?

Tags: gnome, configuration, gsettings

I´m looking for a command to set / change Gnome 3 parameter for all users. Gsettings works fine but only for one user.

Answer (score 1):

See [How to make applications pinned in launcher appear for all users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73096/how-to-make-applications-pinned-in-launcher-appear-for-all-users) for related question.

Afaik there is currently no solution to globally reset a single dconf-setting. User changes are stored in `~/.config/dconf/user`. If you delete this file you reset all dconf keys to defaults.