# Preventing users from changing pinned applications in the launcher?

Tags: launcher, configuration

I am currently trying to setup the Ubuntu clients in my work place to have specific programs in the Launcher (e.g. MATLAB), which I was actually able to do successfully using this method:

[How to make applications pinned in launcher appear for all users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73096/how-to-make-applications-pinned-in-launcher-appear-for-all-users/141346#141346)

However, this only works for users logging in for the first time. What I need is to be able to create something like the schema override that will apply when the machine reboots or users login (either will be enough).

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks` (or create it if it does not exist), and create the following file. You can choose the filename.

```
# prevent changes to pinned applications
/com/canonical/Unity/Launcher/favorites
```

Then run the following command in a terminal. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo dconf update
```

Comment: This is the 2nd or 3rd question where it's been suggested to use a lock file which seemingly makes sense. However has anyone actually gotten it to work in Ubuntu? I don't see it preventing a user from changing a 'locked' key.