# How do I configure the default applications on the launcher on a LiveCD?

Tags: unity

How can one edit unity bar default apps within a livecd? In other words if you boot ubuntu 12.04 livecd you will see in the unity bar, firefox, libreoffice, Ubuntu software center, etc. Well I need to customize a 12.04 livecd so that upon boot you will see my own selected apps ie: chromium, ubuntu-tweak, etc. Please dont link me to remastersys or myunity or ubuntu-tweak or ccsm. No graphical applications to be used. The iso is being built via chroot meaning i need the actual file(s) location: /usr/share/unity-2d.....something along those lines.

Comment: Did you read this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Comment: Yes i did read and am using to build iso but it does not say how to change default unity bar applications.

Comment: stlsaint, have you found a solution? ( [Question 50990](http://askubuntu.com/questions/50990) may be related)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what works for me for customizing a 12.04.1 liveCD:

```
echo "[com.canonical.Unity.Launcher]
favorites=['nautilus-home.desktop', 'firefox.desktop', 'ubuntu-software-center.desktop', 'otherapp1.desktop', 'otherapp2.desktop']" > /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_local-unity-launcher.gschema.override
glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

(all in chroot)

Answer (score 1):

thanks for saving me a long search of documents I would not be reading to find the path

```
# 
$ cd /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
#
```

For customizing a system look, feel, and more this is a good start for overrides but you can do it another way as well I did not test your format but wanted to get to the actual settings and change them myself not override them, so I found another discussion on the subject...
http://ubuntu.5.n6.nabble.com/configuring-unity-launcher-for-200-users-tp4977659p4977772.html

which leads you to this answer:
https://askubuntu.com/a/65901/112263

Comment: **Could you improve your answer?** That folder is useful but you didn't help to the user with **only** that. Because your information is not about *how to* modify something, but where that something is.

Answer (score 0):

These articles should help:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/minimal (in case you want to really customize your ubuntu from the ground up)

**Edit**: I had forgotten about this method of creating a disk image from an existing installation. When I had tried this a few years back, I installed Ubuntu on a virtual machine, customized it to my liking, then followed the directions in the tutorial.

[Make a live CD/DVD/Bootable flash from your harddisk installation](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=688872)

Comment: Thanks for response but no. Those links do not provide anything regarding what I am trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, but unless you are going to use one of the apps you said you didn't want to use in the OP, this is the only way you are going to customize your Ubuntu live CD. Once it's burned, what you see is what you get. The Live CD makes no permanent changes to the computer (other than install if you direct it to do so), which means that it cannot maintain any changes you make to the OS on the live CD. If you want to change the default programs on the live CD, you have to build your own using a GUI tool or using the command line methods above, then burn the customized image.

Comment: To clarify, you cannot make persistent changes to a live CD, but you can make changes to a disk image before it has been burned. You can make persistent changes to your HDD from the live CD (such as installing onto the HDD, or repairing an installation on the HDD, or moving files within or between (a) HDD(s)), but you cannot make persistent changes to the live CD itself unless you make the customizations before burning the disk.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but that is exactly what i am trying to do...BUILD the livecd by hand. I am using the documentation posted before but now i need to change unity bar default apps.

Comment: Ah, I see where the misunderstanding was. Sorry I can't help you with anything unity-specific as I'm just figuring it all out myself.